# How to compare strings in different languages (javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a function that compares two strings, no matter the language. Example:

let string1 = 'hola' //Spanish
let string2 = 'hi' //english

console.log (string1 === string2) //true as expected result

Is there a way to compare strings in different languages.

Regards!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This isn't about "comparing strings." It's about translating a word from one language to another and seeing if it matches the word you have from the other language. Doing machine translation is a **huge** complicated topic, not least because sometimes a word doesn't have any direct translation. You're basically asking "How do I do machine translation" which is far too broad and open-ended a question for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: But that doesn’t make sense? Most words don’t have an exact equivalent in each language

Comment: i thought i was the only one confused about the question...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, not really. Doesn't make much sense either considering that each word might have different meaning in each language depending on context.

Best you can do is try to translate the words and try to find matches in one of the many translations, or use an embedding model for those specific languages and see if the vectors are similar.

Answer (score -1):

The only idea that I have right now is to declare 2 Maps for both languages and then get the key:

```
var spEn = new Map();
spEn.set('hola', 'hi');

var enSp = new Map();
spEn.set('hi', 'hola');

function spanishEnglish(spanish, en){
  translation = spEn.get(spanish);
  return translation === en;
}

function englishSpanish(en, spanish){
  translation = enSp.get(en);
  return translation === spanish;
}

console.log(spanishEnglish('hola', 'hi'))
console.log(englishSpanish('hi', 'hola'))
```

However this is a just a rudimentary example. There are tons of things you need to pay attention to :)